# How to solve undefined variable and undefined property warnings?

Tags: php, function, variables, properties, warnings

I have `$name` and `$age` defined in `set_name()` and `set_age`.
Please check index.php:

```php
<?php
// This part needs some fixing.
class Pet {
    public $name;
    public $age;    

    // get() and set() functions for name
    function set_name($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    function get_name() {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    // get() and set() functions for age
    function set_age($age) {
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    function get_age() {
        return $this->$name;
    }
}
.....
```

Edit:
This problem is fixed. No need for new answers!

Comment: you cannot call `makeSound(sound);` in a class body. The compiler assumes that you try to declare a method there, which fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need constructor for your classes and don't do the `makeSound` method in your Pet class `static`. Try this:

```
public Cat(){
  makeSound(sound);
}

public Dog(){
  makeSound(sound);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method declaration is wrong. If a parent has an implemented version of a function, you do not need to declare it in the subclass. But even if you would want to, the correct way to do it (thus overriding the parent function) would be:

```java
void makeSound(String sound) {
        System.out.println("Hi, I make a " + sound);
    }
```

The use of a static keyword would not make much sense. A static method is a method that is part of the class and not of the created objects. Meaning you could call the method like this `Pets.makeSound(...)`

Comment: I think he is not trying to override it but to call it. But since he does it inside the body of the class it doesn't work. On a side note I do agree that the `static` keyword doesn't make much sense here.